# editing individual lines in svg file with javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, svg

Not really sure if this can be done- but I've made an image as a google drawing, and downloaded it as an svg file. The drawing only consists of individual lines connected at the ends, some of the lines being kind of oddly skewed. I am including the entire svg into an html doc using `<img src="my_svg">`

I was hoping to edit some of these lines based on user input so the backend will just be scaling some of these lines. But the image needs to stay connected.

Is there away to maybe grab the individual lines in the image and adjust their size? I know it can probably be done in Illustrator or something but I'm not using it, I would like this to completely be done in Javascript (open to suggestions using other languages/methods, I just initially planned for this to be a webapp)

I've seen that editing svg with jquery seems to be a powerful way to interact with svg's but nothing specific to what I am trying to do.

Comment: You can't do anything with SVG data if you include it via an <img> tag. You'd need to include it via an <object> or <iframe> tag. The rest of your question is rather too broad. What you need is a tutorial on SVG, there are plenty around.

Comment: I would down vote Robert for mentioning object and iframe - but got a valid point for including it in a `<img>` and this being to broad

Comment: Use some of the FileReader, blob.slice techniques